# Repetir áudio toda vez que botão for clicado - Javascript e HTML

Tags: javascript, html, áudio, jsx

Quero que o áudio repita do inicio toda vez q o botão for pressionado. Ao invés disso ele só repete após o áudio terminar.
(OBS: Estou usando JSX)

Javascript

```
playShot() {
    var audio = document.getElementById('shot');
    audio.play();
}
```

HTML

```
<a onClick={() => this.playShot()} style={{zIndex: 5}} id="gat"><img src={gate2}/></a>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Altere a propriedade `currentTime` do elemento `audio`.

```
playShot() {
    let audio = document.getElementById('shot');
    audio.currentTime = 0
    audio.play(); // É opcional caso o play já esteja em execução.
}
```

Comment: Funcionou! Obrigado amigo, pela solução e também pela sugestão do let. Sou novo em programação e tenho muito a aprender.

Comment: Você diz que é opcional se o `play()` já estiver em execução. Tem alguma maneira de verificar isso? Tipo o objeto `áudio` lança algum evento que terminou a execução?

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado é possível verificar utilizando a propriedade `audio.paused` e ao final da execução do áudio, o player irá lançar um evento para `audio.onended()`